# Is field injection legitimate in a test class for a Spring Data repository?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-data

I want to write an integration test for a Spring Data repository and wonder what's the preferred way to make the repository available in the test class.

When testing my own plain old services, I use something like this to avoid having to use field injection, because field injection should not be used [according to Spring Data project lead Oliver Gierke](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/):

```
public class myServiceTest {

   private MyService myService;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
       myService = new MyService();
   }

   [...]
}
```

But Spring Data repositories are defined as interfaces without an implementation because the Spring magic creates the implementation dynamically.

```
public interface FruitRepository extends CrudRepository<Fruit, Long> {

    List<Fruit> findByName(String name);
}
```

Therefore there is no constructor I could use like this.

Using constructor injection, as in the follwoing example, also does not work, because it yields an Exception when trying to run the test:

```
@Autowired
public MyServiceTest(MyService myService) {
    this.myService = myService;
}

java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public zero-argument constructor
```

As far as I can see, the only option I'm left with is injecting the repository via field injection as in the following working example:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class FruitRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private FruitRepository fruitRepository;

    @Test
    public void findByNameFindsAnExistingFruit() {

        fruitRepository.deleteAll();
        fruitRepository.save(new Fruit("Orange"));
        List<Fruit> foundFruits = fruitRepository.findByName("Orange");

        assertFalse(foundFruits.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void findByNameDoesNotFindANonExistingFruit() {

        fruitRepository.deleteAll();
        fruitRepository.save(new Fruit("Apple"));
        List<Fruit> foundFruits = fruitRepository.findByName("Orange");

        assertTrue(foundFruits.isEmpty());
    } 
}
```

So, my question is: Is this a legitimate exception to the rule to avoid field injection or am I missing something? Or am I maybe overthinking this, because field injection is okay to use in test classes anyway?

Comment: Technically it is possible but you should prefer **constructor injection**. It makes your dependencies more explicit and lets you declare the fields holding your dependencies `final`.

Comment: Hi Tomothy, I know that. In my question I linked to the article by Oliver Gierke where he explains why constructor injection is preferred. This is not what I'm asking. Constructor injection is not possible in the case I'm describing. I stated that pretty clearly in my question, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For tests, this is perfectly fine.

1. With the current version of JUnit there is really no reasonable way to do it differently.
2. The point of preferring constructor injection is that other pieces of code can instantiate the class properly without using any reflection magic. But nobody but JUnit will try to instantiate your tests, so the argument is void.
3. The integration tests of Spring Data itself use this approach. See for example here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/UserRepositoryTests.java#L97 Note that Oliver is among the authors so I guess he approves as well.